# Gtk, custom modal dialog

Tags: gtk

I am trying to make sustom modal dialog with glade.
For this I use "dialog box" from "toplevels", set transient_for_window and modal variables properly. Then I put widgets to table all packed into dialog-vbox.
And this works OK, as expected.

But, when I need more complex GUI, like I need now, and pack into dialog-vbox scrolledwindow> viewport> aspectframe> table> and then place widgets in table this dialog becomes no more modal! After some playing I conclude that it is obvious that problems with modality starts with scrolledwindow.

Is it allowed to put such complex GUI in dialog? If yes - why my dialog lost modality with gtkscrollwindow, if no, how people do such tasks? In my case I'm trying to make modal dialog which can be connected to different projects (say reusable).

GUI:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="2.24"/>
  <!-- interface-naming-policy project-wide -->
  <object class="GtkDialog" id="dialog1">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="border_width">5</property>
    <property name="type_hint">dialog</property>
    <property name="skip_taskbar_hint">True</property>
    <child internal-child="vbox">
      <object class="GtkVBox" id="dialog-vbox1">
    <property name="visible">True</property>
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="spacing">2</property>
    <child internal-child="action_area">
      <object class="GtkHButtonBox" id="dialog-action_area1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="layout_style">end</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="button1">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Cancel</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
            <property name="use_action_appearance">False</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">False</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="button2">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">OK</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
            <property name="use_action_appearance">False</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">False</property>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
      <packing>
        <property name="expand">False</property>
        <property name="fill">True</property>
        <property name="pack_type">end</property>
        <property name="position">0</property>
      </packing>
    </child>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkScrolledWindow" id="scrolledwindow1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">True</property>
        <property name="hscrollbar_policy">automatic</property>
        <property name="vscrollbar_policy">automatic</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkViewport" id="viewport1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkTable" id="table1">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="n_rows">10</property>
                <property name="n_columns">2</property>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkEntry" id="entry1">
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                    <property name="invisible_char">•</property>
                    <property name="invisible_char_set">True</property>
                    <property name="primary_icon_activatable">False</property>
                    <property name="secondary_icon_activatable">False</property>
                    <property name="primary_icon_sensitive">True</property>
                    <property name="secondary_icon_sensitive">True</property>
                  </object>
                  <packing>
                    <property name="left_attach">1</property>
                    <property name="right_attach">2</property>
                    <property name="top_attach">2</property>
                    <property name="bottom_attach">3</property>
                  </packing>
                </child>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkLabel" id="label1">
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                    <property name="label" translatable="yes">label</property>
                  </object>
                  <packing>
                    <property name="top_attach">2</property>
                    <property name="bottom_attach">3</property>
                  </packing>
                </child>
              </object>
            </child>
          </object>
        </child>
      </object>
      <packing>
        <property name="expand">True</property>
        <property name="fill">True</property>
        <property name="position">2</property>
      </packing>
    </child>
      </object>
    </child>
    <action-widgets>
      <action-widget response="0">button1</action-widget>
      <action-widget response="0">button2</action-widget>
    </action-widgets>
  </object>
</interface>
```

C:

```
    int dlgmodal(GtkWidget *mainwindow, char* fmw)
{
    builder = gtk_builder_new();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file(builder, "external0.glade", NULL);
    dialog1  = GTK_DIALOG(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "dialog1"));
    entry1 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "entry1"));
    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);
    g_object_unref(G_OBJECT(builder));

    gtk_entry_set_text(GTK_ENTRY(entry1), fmw);

    gtk_window_set_modal(GTK_WINDOW(GTK_DIALOG(dialog1)), TRUE);
    gtk_window_set_transient_for(GTK_WINDOW(GTK_DIALOG(dialog1)), GTK_WINDOW(mainwindow));

    //
    int x, y;
    gdk_window_get_origin(GDK_WINDOW(GTK_WIDGET(mainwindow)->window), &x, &y);
    gtk_window_move(GTK_WINDOW(dialog1), x+8, y);

    //
    int dlgresponse;
    dlgresponse = gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(dialog1));

    gtk_widget_destroy(GTK_WIDGET(GTK_DIALOG(dialog1)));
    return dlgresponse;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8940687

Comment: WOW! Exact this! After a week of fighting with modal dialogs and windows, yesterday I conclude that gtkscrolledwindow screws. What are options now? Can I maybe upgrade my gtk to fixed version or what? I still uses gtk2.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not aware of any fix or workaround to this; you'll have to wait until Ubuntu fixes their scrollbar replacement thingy.

Comment: Thanks Johannes. You helped me a lot by knowing that fault isn't in my programming. I tested now on different OS than Ubuntu and things works as expected.